# Can't remove dynamically added class

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm stumped, I swear I must be missing some simple as this isn't making any sense to me currently.

Going forward I'm looking to remove jQuery from projects, this seems like it should be the most simple of tasks but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

I've added a class to an element which I can't seem to remove.

Note: `form-input` is added to the markup and `invalid` is added dynamically

```
const telephoneInput = document.querySelector('#form-telephone');

console.log(telephoneInput.classList); // DOMTokenList [ "form-input", "invalid" ]

telephoneInput.classList.remove('invalid');

console.log(telephoneInput.classList); // DOMTokenList [ "form-input" ]
```

From this the DOMTokenList/classList is updated, however the DOM is not, the class and its effects are still present.

Element in DOM after above has run: 
`<input name="form-telephone" id="form-telephone" class="form-input invalid" type="tel">`

Now if I change the previous test to remove the class which was added in the original markup `form-input` it works as expected...

```
const telephoneInput = document.querySelector('#form-telephone');

console.log(telephoneInput.classList); // DOMTokenList [ "form-input", "invalid" ]

telephoneInput.classList.remove('form-input');

console.log(telephoneInput.classList); // DOMTokenList [ "invalid" ]
```

After this the DOMTokenList/classList is again updated, this time the DOM is as well.

Element in DOM after above has run:
`<input name="form-telephone" id="form-telephone" class="invalid" type="tel">`

Am I missing something here, is the adding of the class `invalid` changing something that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

The `:invalid` CSS pseudo-class represents any  or other  element whose contents fail to validate. The class is added by default whenever a form or an input is invalid. You can't change this behavior. But, you can override it:

```
input:invalid {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

This pseudo-class is useful for highlighting field errors for the user.

Comment: This is a custom validation process where the ```:invalid``` pseudo-class isn't being used on all elements (only defaulted places such as email). I'm running my own regular expression tests and passing an invalid class to elements (and containers for things such as radios where the actual state is hidden therefore an ```:invalid``` on the input would be redundant).

In the actual codebase I'm looping over the collection of failed elements and trying to remove the invalid class with no luck, I just tested and used the single telephone example for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.mystyle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to add the "mystyle" class to DIV.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">add</button>
<button onclick="myFunction1()">remove</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The classList property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div id="myDIV">
I am a DIV element
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.add("mystyle");
}
function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("myDIV").classList.remove("mystyle");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can see my example here. I am adding removing without any problem. So this is not an error because of dynamically added class, this is the problem with "invalid" class, which is auto class for form fields.

Suggestion:  Use a different class for your purpose

Comment: I've ran a similar test here... https://jsfiddle.net/2tfe1Lgc/ this gives the same result but using the class "invalid", so I don't think the problem is using the name invalid either. I think there may be a deeper problem with the codebase